# Cant check boolean in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting values from a model, but while checking the values it always goes in to the `else` part of the conditions. I am alerting the values I am getting and they are correct, but in the `if` condition it doesn't get satisfied. I even tried with `===`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mark = new Boolean(@Model.isMarketing);
  var revenue = new Boolean(@Model.isRevenue);
  var staff = new Boolean(@Model.isStaff);

  if (revenue == true) {
    $("input[name=isRevenue][value='isRevenue']").prop("checked", true);
  } else if (staff == true) {
    $("input[name=isRevenue][value='isStaff']").prop("checked", true);
  } else if (mark === true) {
    $("input[name=isRevenue][value='isMarketing']").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("input[name=isRevenue][value='None']").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

Comment: try using directly, var mark = '@Model.isMarketing'; for dynamic variable in javascript and then make condition

Comment: don't compare it with `true`. Simply change the conditions to `if(revenue)` ...

Comment: Have you checked what the output of the `@Model.isXXX` properties is, and also what the values of `mark` and the other variables are? It seems like they are being set to `false`.

Comment: @Dhiren i did that also, but it didnt work

Comment: For this type of things, check the value in console with debugging not with alert! Check what the value you are getting; is it a string or boolean? you might be getting 'true' or 'false'

Comment: @w1n5rx that is also not working

Comment: @RuchitaAjmera it won't fix the problem, it's just better logic

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i checked value i am getting true

Comment: Right, but ***what*** are you getting `true` from? The model or the variable? Are you sure the `if` condition isn't hitting, or is it the fact that your selectors are wrong. To help you more effectively we need to see what the values in the Model are, and also your HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan from both

Comment: Then your selectors are wrong.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what should i do then?

Comment: @RuchitaAjmera add on the very first line just after document ready function add " var mark = '@Model.isMarketing'; debugger " and see in the console what you are getting true,false or 'true','false' as string value?

Comment: @Dhiren getting "True"

Comment: Add your HTML to the question as I asked previously. There's no issue in your JS, so long as the variables are set correctly as you claim, so the problem has to be elsewhere. You're not making it easy to help you.

Comment: I changed my condition to "True" and its working

Comment: @RuchitaAjmera now check what you are getting from new Boolean('@Model.isMarketing') in debug mode

Comment: @RuchitaAjmera model values always gives this kind of strange values in javascript so first check the values in debugger and then make conditions based on that

Comment: You use `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); var mark = model.isMarketing; if (mark) { ...` - but the fact you have a checkbox with `value='isRevenue'` makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're getting not true or "true" from @Model.isMarketing, @Model.isRevenue etc. 
And never use the === in condition when you using new Boolean(true) it won't equal true with using ===.

I wanna suggest you several approaches:
1. Use !! instead of new Boolean(@Model.isMarketing);
 e.g.

```
var mark = !!@Model.isMarketing;
```

2. Just remove new Boolean() and use if like:

```
var mark = @Model.isMarketing;
if(mark) {
 //do smth.
}
 else {
//do smth else
};
```

Also I wanna suggest how to improve your code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var trueMark = 'True';
    var mark = trueMark === @Model.isMarketing;
    var revenue = trueMark === @Model.isRevenue;
    var staff = trueMark === @Model.isStaff;

    var value = 'None';
    if (revenue) {
        value = 'isRevenue';
    }
    else if (staff) {
        value = 'isStaff';
    }
    else if (mark) {
        value = 'isMarketing';
    }

    $("input[name=isRevenue][value="+ value + "]").prop("checked", true);    

});
```

Please, make sure that you're getting right values from @Model

Comment: Improved the code. var mark = !!@Model.isMarketing; didnt work for me as its giving me "True" as string but optimized code as per your code

Comment: Did you make sure that it always gives you "True" at least in one of the variables? 
Because it may be the cause why you always got to "else" block.